# Require multiple strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to force my controller to require a few different parameters when they are passed. Any ideas how to do this in one line? (or the proper way to do it)

```
params.require(:facebook_message).require(:access_token)
params.require(:facebook_message).require(:facebook_user_id)
params.require(:facebook_message).require(:message_body)
params.require(:facebook_message).permit(
    :access_token, :facebook_user_id, :message_body, :message_subject
)
```

Answer (score 2):

params.require currently allows only one parameter:

```
### File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb, line 182
def require(key)
  self[key].presence || raise(ParameterMissing.new(key))
end
```

Comment: It only allows one parameter: "wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)"

Comment: You're right. Perhaps you could use a block to set these up, but it won't save you any lines with only three required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
%i(access_token facebook_user_id message_body).each do |param_key|
  params.require(:facebook_message).require(param_key)
end
params.require(:facebook_message).permit(
    :access_token, :facebook_user_id, :message_body, :message_subject
)
```

Not exactly a one-liner but it saves up some space...